# Twitter bootstrap divide row-fluid by available space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html, fluid

I have the following usecase.
I need to draw 6 blocks of html divs and break it down to by the available space.
The image bellow will demonstrate how is it suppose to be.
Can you please have a look at this code and tell me what is the problems with my spans?
http://jsfiddle.net/DWZLE/ 
Thanks
[image]

here is how the code starts:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 68%;">
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="span4">
            <div>
                <img src="http://trialx.com/curetalk/wp-content/blogs.dir/7/files/2011/05/diseases/Globus-3-small.gif" />
            </div>
            <h3><a href="http://www.google.com">We speak your language</a></h3>
            <p>
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            </p> 
        </div>...
```

**Update**
I have divided it to two rows, now, it breaks down but from 3 in a row two 1 on a row.
And, it is not centered. see here http://jsfiddle.net/DWZLE/

Comment: You should add bootstrap-responsive.css to the fiddle or use http://bootply.com instead

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it like that.

In boostrap the first element in each row, doesn't have margin-left, so that it can fit the other elements, so when you add 6 span4 the 4 element (which is the first element in the second row) will have margin-left and it will push the orher elements.

So you should make 2 rows with 3 elements in each one.

Comment: I dind't see anything change from the updated version, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/DWZLE/1/ that's what I had in mind.

Comment: I changed the link. anyway, in your code, it breaks down from 3 to on and not from 3 to 2 and than one (like my image). and it is not centered. Thanks

Comment: Yep that is normal when you use fluid rows, since the elements have calculated widths in % it won't break at all, if you want them to brake you should use normal ".row", not ".fluid-row".

Comment: hmmm... .row has some bad behavior, the rows are jumping up and down when I shrink the screen, I should check for another framework... Thanks

Comment: For mobile and tablet can you import bootstrap-responsive.css

Answer (score 0):

I agree with drip. Fine explained.

You can make it.

```
One Row. (Max span count 12)
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span4">
      ...
   </div
   <div class="span4">
      ...
   </div
   <div class="span4">
      ...
   </div
</div>

Two Row
<div class="row-fluid">
   ...
</div>
```